# How to re-render updated values in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to loop through rainbow colors for infinite time at fix interval and update that color in browser DOM.

Color value is changing after every half second. But it is not re-rendering in DOM.

```
import React from 'react'

const Rainbow = (WrapedComponent) =>{

        const colors = ['violet', 'indigo', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red'];

        let i=0;
        let newColor;


        setInterval(() => {
            newColor = colors[i];
            if (i === (colors.length - 1)) {
                i = 0;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }, 500);


        let newStyle = {
            color: newColor
        }


    return (props) => {
        return (
            <div style={newStyle}>
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
                <WrapedComponent {...props}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Rainbow
```

Comment: Has nothing to do with React

Comment: am not sure what you are asking, your code seems to work. click RUN CODE SNIPPET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are updating `newColor` just fine; the issue is that `newStyle` (and `newStyle.color`) is only assigned to once. Although `newStyle.color` initially references the *first value* of `newColor`, it's not the same thing as `newStyle.color` constantly referencing future values of `newColor`.

Simply change `newColor = colors[i]` in your timeout to `newStyle.color = colors[i]` to update that object. If you want `newStyle` to be applied to something in the DOM, you'll of course need to make sure that code is in place as well.

**Edit:**

Now that it's clarified that this is React, you'll need some changes. React isn't going to monitor local variables for changes and apply those changes to the DOM. Instead you have to specifically trigger the update in React. The most straightforward way to do this is through *state*. Changes to state cause a re-render. You'll also want to make your timer interval into an *effect* that can be turned off when the component is unmounted.

```
import React from 'react'
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

const colors = ['violet', 'indigo', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red'];

const Rainbow = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return (props) => {
    const [color, setColor] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
      const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        setColor((color + 1) % colors.length);
      }, 500);
      return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
    }, [color]);

    return (
      <div style={{ color: colors[color] }}>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <WrappedComponent {...props}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Rainbow
```

Comment: thx alot man.. but i didn't got what u did here.. i m half way in react course. Thx again u really tried to help.

Comment: `useEffect` and `useState` can be kind of mind bending, but understanding them will help you a lot. Good luck with your studies!

Comment: Finally got it, Very clear Explanation. I was changing value outside state, thats why it was not re-rendering updated value.. Thx alot @Jacob

Answer (score 2):

Rather than creating a new scope and recursively calling loopforver... forever... and creating a new setTimeout each time, just use setInterval.  I also added newStyle.color into the loop because otherwise you're never setting anything.  newstyle.color = newColor only happens once, it seems like you're expecting it to be bound in some way.

```
const colors = ['violet', 'indigo', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow',
  'orange', 'red'
];

let i = 0;
let newColor;
let newStyle = {};
let intervalId = window.setInterval(() => {
    newStyle.color = colors[i];
    //Apply newStyle to some dom element here if need be
    i++
    if (i === 6) {
        i = 0;
    }

}, 500);

//When you're ready to be done
window.clearInterval(intervalId);
```

Answer (score 1):

You had your question originally tagged with `reactjs` before that was removed because it's not clear where react comes into play from your example code. However, you would simply call `this.setState()` in place of the `console.log()` to update the `color` property in your component's state.

And then there are a few other things to note:

1. Instead of calling the function via `setTimeout()` over and over again, use `setInterval()` instead.
2. Your code never reached `"red"`, because the index was reset before. I also changed the code to take the array's length into account dynamically without it being hard-coded.

```js
const colors = ['violet', 'indigo', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red'];

let i = 0;
let newColor;

setInterval(() => {
  newColor = colors[i];
  document.documentElement.style.backgroundColor = newColor;
  // this is where you would call
  // this.setState({color: newColor});
  if (i === (colors.length - 1)) {
    i = 0;
  } else {
    i++;
  }
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

the setTimeout method times out for 500ms and is executing for ever and by the time the setTimeout is executed, the

```
    let newStyle = {
      color: newColor
    }
```

is already executed.  That's the reason you are not able to get the newColor.